# jr-crop Plugin not work in version greater than android 5.1.1

Tags: android, cordova

i use plugin in my app to crop images and it works at ios and android version 4 and 5.0
but for versions like 5.1.1 or 6.0
crop not appear and image only that appear
how i fix this issue in new versions?

Answer (score 0):

As its mentioned in the [official github page](https://github.com/JrSchild/jr-crop) of jr-crop plugin, its offically supported only for iOS but may work well in Android. The excerpt from the official page is as follows:

> Though I'm only supporting iOS, I did get reports that it's working well on Android. If it doesn't, feel free to fork and update my codebase.

So may be for Android 5.1.x and above, you may have to extend the plugin.